# Optimization question/ calculus

Tags: calculus, derivatives

The curve $y = x^2 – 5$ is given.

A point P on the curve has $x$-coordinate equal to $a$.

(a) Show that the distance OP is $\sqrt{a^4 -9a^2 + 25}$

(b) Find the values of a for which the curve is closest to the origin.

I do not understand how to approach this question. Can someone help me to get started ? i do not understand what they mean by the distance OP. There is no curve showing point P.. so I have no idea where that is supposed to be on the graph.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess $O$ means the origin. If a point $P$ on the curve has $x$ coordinate $a$ then its $y$ coordinate must be $a^2-5$. So the question is to find the distance between $(0,0)$ and $(a,a^2-5)$, and find the value of $a$ for which this distance is minimized. Can you proceed now?

Comment: ohh ok that makes sense, thanks i understand it now

Answer (score 1):

a)$$P(a,{a^2-5})$$
$$PO=\sqrt{(a-0)^2+(a^2-5-0)^2}=\sqrt{a^4−9a^2+25}$$
b)find min for function $f(a)={a^4−9a^2+25}$